# NameError: name 'textSuface' is not defined

Tags: python, pygame

After the player rect has collided with the window width I am now getting an error suggesting that textSurface has not been defined even though it has been defined under def message_display(text):
The help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my source code:

https://pythonprogramming.net/displaying-text-pygame-screen/?completed=/adding-boundaries-pygame-video-game/
And here is the source video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dX57H9qecCU&index=5&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdLkP8MrOXLe_rKuf6r80KO

Contrasting here is my code:

```
# This just imports all the Pygame modules 
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

# This initates your colors
black = (0,0,0)
# You have 256 color options so you only use 255 because one of those is 0
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

plyrImg_width = 30

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Bit Racer')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

plyrImg = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01 double size.png')

def player(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(plyrImg,(x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSuface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()


def killed():
    message_display('You Died')


def game_loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
#         This handles any and all events in the game
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            print(event)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change

#        Make sure to write the background before the player
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        player(x,y)

        if x > display_width - plyrImg_width or  x < 0:
            killed()


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
#     This is how you un-initiate pygame
#     This is what closes the window so always have this

# If you want to end your game loop enter this
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You have a typo. It's in the question title. `textSuface` should be `textSurface`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to spell it correctly.  Surface, not suface.

Comment: Sorry! I'm a dunce, I've been siting at the computer for about 10+ hours and my brain didn't pick that up!

Comment: Read the error messages more than you read the code. If you look at the error message and dismiss the contents and try to debug the program by just scanning down looking for errors you will not be very successful. Learn to understand what the error messages *actually tell* you. They are there to *help you*.